# xsd choice with multiple xsd:element with difference MaxOccurs

Tags: xml, xsd

Am trying to modify the legacy xsd file which contains xsd choice with maxOccurs='unbound'. I have a requirement to change a child xsd:element to appear only once.

Sample existing code: Where I need to restrict element'B' to occur only once and rest behave as usual.

```
<xsd:complexType name="test">
    <xsd:choice  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="A"/>
        <xsd:element name="B"/>
        <xsd:element name="C"/>
        <xsd:element name="D"/>
        <xsd:element name="E"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Below are My approach :

a)

```
<xsd:complexType name="test">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="E" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

b)

```
<xsd:complexType name="test">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="C" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="E" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Sample valid XML: "<node/><C/><C/><B/><A/></node>"

Sample invalid XML: "<node/><C/><C/><B/><B/><A/></node>"

None of these works. Any advice here please ,

Comment: You need explain your requirements using some examples - at least one valid and one invalid XML.

Comment: Also...a) and b) look the same to me.

Comment: If `A` is required once, you can bracket it in a sequence between two `xsd:choice[@maxOccurs="unbounded"]`s containing the rest of the elements.  If `A` is optional, you'll need to manage that with an XSD 1.1 assertion instead, else you'll run afoul of the Unique Particle Attribution constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially trying to create a collection of A, B, C, D, E objects, but restrict the collection to contain at most one instance of B. This is an awkward data structure that will likely create headaches elsewhere. Instead, take B out of the collection entirely. For example, try something like:

```
<xsd:complexType name="test">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:choice  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element name="A"/>
      <xsd:element name="C"/>
      <xsd:element name="D"/>
      <xsd:element name="E"/>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

If you absolutely need to keep your current data structure, kjhughes' suggestion on XSD 1.1 assertions may help.